# Can't add new command when connection is in closed state (knex.js with mysql2 + mysql8 + node.js 16)

Tags: node.js, knex.js, node-mysql2

I have an issue after few hours of work with this setup:

- knex.js (mysql2)
- mysql8
- node.js 16 (docker FROM node:16)

---

**"Can't add new command when connection is in closed state"**

---

With this setup:

```
      config: {
        client: 'mysql2',
        connection: {
          host: '11.11.11.11',
          user: 'some',
          password: 'some',
          database: 'some',
          timezone: "+00:00",
          charset: "utf8mb4"
        }
      },
      pool: {
        min: 1,
        max: 10
      }
```

This cant be solved only by restart of node.js, but then after few hours happens again

Comment: Also having this issue for about a month now looked through our commits multiple times and can't find any related changes

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have this issue too. There was an issue open in the mysql2 GitHub, but they devs won't fix it and they closed the issue.